# How do I center this <div>

Tags: css, html, center

I'm trying to center this div background at [www.bakoproduction.com](http://www.bakoproduction.com).  When I add `margin: auto` to the css `.div.background img` it centers the image but it doesn't show the rest of the images. Here is my css if anyone can help me I would really appreciate it.

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.fondolineas {
    background-image: url(fondo.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.demo-ad-top{
    margin:20px 0;
}
.gradient {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(  linear,  left bottom,  left top,  color-stop(0.28, rgb(255,201,116)),  color-stop(0.64, rgb(228,143,10)) );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(  center bottom,  rgb(255,201,116) 28%,  rgb(228,143,10) 64% );
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    padding:5px;
}

h1 {
    font:bold 14px/1.5em "Trebuchet MS", Trebuchet, Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
div.background {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    alignment-adjust: central;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
}
div.background img {
    position:fixed;
    list-style: none;
    left:auto;
    top:auto;
}
div.background ul li.show {
    z-index:500
}
.content {
    width:1200px;
    margin-left:auto
    margin-right:auto
    background:#fff;
    padding:30px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Use this for preparing questions: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Bibi, you've got a couple missing semicolons in `.content`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the `img`s positioned fixed to the screen, `margin:auto` wont center them. Try this instead:

```
div.background img {
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    top:auto;
    margin-left:-600px; /* Half of the image's width */
}
```

Comment: Wow! You guys are awesome, thank you so much!! This worked perfectly. Keep rocking :) I'm still learning. Big hug!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
background:no-repeat;
background-image:url(../Images/Home/Banner.png);
background-position:center;
```

and to contain or stretch the background with your dimensions you have to use this

```
background-size: contain;
```

Comment: Hey!! Thanks for your answer, I finally could do it. Kisses.

Answer (score 0):

Your images will not respond to setting their margins to be `auto`, because you're using `position: fixed;`. Instead, center it by setting both `left` and `right` to `0`.

```
div.background img {
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey Nightfirecat, thanks for your help! If I could I would give you guys points but I can't do it yet because I'm new on the site. But you guys really help me, I'm so happy :) THANKS!

Comment: Not a problem. If you feel that my answer (and the other answers) deserve the votes, just come back later when you *do* have enough reputation. I'm glad we were able to help.